# How do I put a different image into each Card View in a Recycler View?

Tags: java, android

So I wish to add images into my items. Right now, I am able to display words for each CardView in the RecyclerView. However, for pictures, I am unable to do so. I've tried adding listImage<> with the data type as ImageView/Drawable but it still doesn't work (though it did for listData<> but it's datatype is string).
Here's my code in my RecyclerAdapter:

```
class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

public TextView txtDesc;
public ImageView imgView;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    txtDesc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodcourtdesc);
    imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodcourtimg);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }
}

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>{

private List<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> listData, Context context) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodcourt, parent, false);

    return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtDesc.setText(listData.get(position));

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            if(isLongClick){
                Toast.makeText(context, listData.get(position) + " chosen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, listData.get(position) + " chosen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my code when inserting the data

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_foodcourt);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listData, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        listData.add("Foodcourt " + i);
    }
```

I used the codes found in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puyiZKvxBa0) to form this RecyclerView/CardView but even after understanding how it works (partially), I'm still unable to assign a photo to each item. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Are the images coming from server or you have it in your drawable?

Comment: @UmangBurman It is from my own drawable.

Comment: Check out my answer please.. I've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are from drawable then write this:

```
Integer[] images = new Integer[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2....}; // Provide 6 Images or it will crash saying null pointer exception
ArrayList<Integer> loadImage = new ArrayList<>();
```

in your activity class.

Then, in your for loop write:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    listData.add("Foodcourt " + i);
    loadImage.add(images[i]);
}
```

Then, make this change,

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listData, loadImage, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, in your adapter make a Arraylist as:

```
ArrayList<Integer> Images = new ArrayList<>();
```

then, modify like below code:

```
public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> listData, List<Integer> listImages, Context context) { 
   this.listData = listData;
   this.Images = listImages;
   this.context = context;
}
```

Finally, in your onBindViewHolder make change as:

```
 holder.imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, Images.get(position)));
```

That's it.. That should display images in each item of recyclerview.. Try it..

Comment: Everything looks good except
    holder.imgView.setImageDrawable(Images.get(position));
It states setImageDrawable in ImageView cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer.. Please check the last line.

Comment: I've made the changes and in the code it seems like nothing was wrong, however when I run it, it crashed. In the fourth and fifth code you gave, there is ArrayList<Integer> and List<Integer>, I've made changes to it as the data type was inconsistent. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add upto 6 files from drawable? What does the error say in logcat?

Comment: Okay, hi an update. Thank you so much. It works now. It was this little ass "loadImage.add(images[i]);", there is no 6th position, only 0 to 5th haha. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah I did. I just changed the code to "loadImage.add(images[i-1]);" so it works. Because there was an error adding images[6] as it does not exists. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer so that anyone looking for the same can know about it.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop code is not at correct place. You are adding the data into the list after passing it into the constructor. Here is the code to fix it:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_foodcourt);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        listData.add("Foodcourt " + i);
    }

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listData, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It worked but thanks for the help anyway. But how do I add images to each of these items?

Comment: Doesn't display anything :(

Comment: No I have shared pastebin link for code sharing. It should look like this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/YlbtCmO.png

Answer (score 0):

`listData` should contain `images` of different `URLs` to show different `images` on different cards in the `listView`.

Comment: The images are actually from my drawable folders How do I get the images even if I were to add them?

Comment: int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};

Comment: You can follow this link as well for better understandings:
https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial